# Invalid Firebase path: testuser@gnail.com. Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a signup page in which I want to check if that particular email entered or mobile phone entered already exists or not.I think _emailText as a string is not accepted but then how to fetch the email and password.
Here's the following code:

```
public boolean userExist(){
    //private Firebase mRef = new Firebase("https://abcdefgh.firebaseio.com/users/");  
    mRef.child(_emailText.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email already exist. Please choose a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                _emailText.setError("Email already exist. Please choose a different one");
                valid = false;
            }
            else{
                email = _emailText.getText().toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mRef.child(_mobileText.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                _mobileText.setError("Mobile Number already exist");
                valid = false;

            }
            else{
                mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });


    return valid;
}
```

And the database structure is like this:

[image]

Comment: Your keys cannot contain periods, as the error states. Replace them with some other characters

Comment: Please edit your post to include the structure of your database

Comment: The structure is that inside "abcdefgh" there is a user in which if you sign up then email, mobile and all are created, what i am trying to do is when signing up fetching those emails and mobiles and comparing to what my edittext contains.

Comment: Again, please [edit] to show your actual database data

Comment: Basically, you would not have been able to *add* data at `mRef.child("testuser@gnail.com")` as the key of an element. Certainly, you are trying to do `mRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("testuser@gnail.com")`?

Comment: I did please see the image.Now the image shows only one ID but there are many ID's present so when a user enters details on sign up page it checks with these email ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child key is `5Ri...`, not an email

You're looking for this

```
mRef = new Firebase("https://abcdefgh.firebaseio.com/");
mRef.child("users")
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo("testuser@gnail.com").addListener...( ) {

};
```

Comment: I did that but I am clicking on create account button and it is still going to next activity and then calling Toast error. But it shouldn't, it should go inside the listener methods first and call listener method and shouldn't go to next activity in the first place.

Comment: If you have additional errors, feel free to create more posts, but this solution is for the specific error you asked about

Comment: @divJ, you cannot write a return after a Firebase listener. The return is **immediate**, the `onDataChange` gets called *after the return* despite being "above the return" in the code. This is how asynchronous code works